# Can't Find Windows 2012 TCP Limits

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, tcp

I have a VPS server running Windows 2012 R2 that is used with a piece of software that makes roughly 15,000 connections in a minute. I noticed some lag and other issues with the VPS, and decided to upgrade to a Dedicated server.

VPS Specs: "4 vCores 3.1 GHz, 8GB Ram, SSD, 100mbit connection"
Dedicated Specs: "Xeon E5-1620 v2 3.7GHz, 64GB RAM, 1gbit connection"

I installed Windows 2012 R2 on it, and noticed a dramatic speed decrease in the software. It was hitting only about 5,000 connections per minute. I thought it might be because this was on a HDD instead of an SSD, so I setup a RAMDisk. There was zero improvement in the performance. I started to look into TCP limitations, thinking the VPS container that was automatically setup for me might be different than my settings. I couldn't find much. I added a ton of options to the TCP Parameters in the registry, and still see no difference.

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters]
"TcpTimedWaitDelay"=dword:0000001e
"MaxUserPort"=dword:0000fffe
"TcpNumConnections"=dword:00fffffe
"TcpMaxDataRetransmissions"=dword:00000005`

The software connects to a single IP address, across multiple ports (~100 ports).

I'm unsure of where to look now. All speed-tests show the dedicated server is significantly faster than the VPS, but the VPS, with a slower connection and less powerful hardware, can reach faster connections per minute.

Any direction to where I can look further would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us more details about what the software is doing? Are these connections to different IP addresses? How many of them are half-open at a time?

Comment: `I added a ton of options to the TCP Parameters in the registry, and still see no difference.` - Perhaps you could enlighten us on exactly what it is that you "added".

Comment: @DavidSchartz added information about it to the post, but also here: the software basically connects to another server I have on a single IP address, across 100 ports. I don't think any should be "half open": the software is supposed to connect, send information, then disconnect.

Comment: @joeqwerty I edited the post to include the settings I changed in the registry. It was based on this post: http://serverfault.com/questions/648424/windows-server-2012-r2-runs-out-of-ephemeral-ports-though-it-shouldnt

Comment: @TeddJohnson Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @avi no I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

Try next changes ([more details](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Performance)).

1. Open an administrator command prompt at %windir%\System32\inetsrv\
2. Run the command below to update the appConcurrentRequestLimit attribute to a suitable number (5000 is the default in IIS7+)

> appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webserver/serverRuntime
>   /appConcurrentRequestLimit:100000

3. Open %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config (Framework64 for 64 bit processes)
4. Configure it
   **Example**

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <configuration>
   <runtime>
       <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="false" />
       <legacyImpersonationPolicy enabled="true"/>
       <alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy enabled="false"/>
       <SymbolReadingPolicy enabled="1" />
       <shadowCopyVerifyByTimestamp enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
   <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" />
   <system.web>
       <applicationPool maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="20000" />
   </system.web>
   </configuration>`